# Rails : get authenticity token from inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to do a POST to another controller from inside a prior controller, how do I get the value for the authenticity_token from inside a controller?

TY,
Fred

Comment: try request.authenticity_token

Comment: I tried that but I get NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticity_token' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0xaf8d2994>):

Answer (score 0):

`authenticity_token` you can get through `params[:authenticity_token]`

Although I'm not sure that your use case (invoke controller from another one) is a good choice.